# Examples of thick subcategory

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'd like to know several examples of thick/Serre subcategory of an abelian category, I have no one in mind now. Help me please!

Comment: I've just found out a candidate: the subcategory contains finite groups of the category of groups.

Answer (score 0):

The classical example, originally considered by Serre, is the Serre subcategory of torsion $A$-modules in the abelian category $A$-modules, where $A$ is a commutative unital ring.  See [Stacks, 0B0J](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B0J) for some details on this examle.